# How to add many divs in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been designing a web infographic with some animations within the page. So I added some JavaScript code in order to trigger the animations as the user reaches them on screen.

My question is how to add many `div` names in a JavaScript sentence?

The name of the div is "`box_info_a`", I just need to add some more, but have no idea how.

This is the code:

```
$(function() 
    var $window = $(window),
        win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1,
        isTouch = Modernizr.touch;
    if (isTouch) {
        $('.revealOnScroll').addClass('box_info_a');
    }
    $window.on('scroll', revealOnScroll);
    function revealOnScroll() {
        var scrolled = $window.scrollTop(),
            win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1;
        // Showed...
        $(".revealOnScroll:not(.box_info_a)").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
            if (scrolled + win_height_padded > offsetTop) {
                if ($this.data('timeout')) {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $this.addClass('box_info_a ' + $this.data('animation'));
                    }, parseInt($this.data('timeout'), 10));
                } else {
                    $this.addClass('box_info_a ' + $this.data('animation'));
                }
            }
        }); // Close Showed...
        // Hidden...
        $(".revealOnScroll.box_info_a").each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this),
                offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
            if (scrolled + win_height_padded < offsetTop) {
                $(this).removeClass('box_info_a lightSpeedIn')
            }
        });
    }
    revealOnScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#trigger').click(function () {
    $('#target').addClass("oneClassToAdd anotherClassToAdd");
  });
});
```

All you have to do is put two classes in the parentheses.

Comment: An example can be found [here](http://liveweave.com/r2efMu). Just click 'Hello Weaver' and two classes are added.